# Looping through XML and adding contents to access table

Tags: xml, vb.net, ms-access

Hey I've got an XML file in which I want to loop through each element (some don't contain values for atk, def, level whilst others do) and add the contents of each element to an access table. No error pops up on debug but the access table only contains the contents of the first element. Here is an example of the XML's contents: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HXCnR.png 
This is the function code:

```
        Dim conn As New OleDbConnection
        conn = New OleDbConnection
        dbprovider = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;"
        Dim databasePath = "Data Source = FULL YUGIOH ACCESS DATABASE.accdb;"
        conn.ConnectionString = dbprovider & databasePath
        Dim ds As New DataSet
        Dim command As OleDbCommand
        ds.ReadXml("C:\Users\1964\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\YGO Access Test v10\bin\Debug\MyData.xml")
        Try
            conn.Open()
            command = New OleDbCommand()
            maxrows = dataSet.Tables(0).Rows.Count

                For Each DtRow As DataRow In ds.Tables(0).Rows
                If Dtrow("level") Is Nothing OrElse IsDBNull(Dtrow("level")) And Dtrow("atk") Is Nothing OrElse IsDBNull(Dtrow("atk")) And Dtrow("def") Is Nothing OrElse IsDBNull(Dtrow("def")) Then
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", Convert.ToString(Dtrow("name")))
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@type", Convert.ToString(Dtrow("type")))
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@type", Convert.ToString(Dtrow("type")))
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@desc", Convert.ToString(Dtrow("desc")))
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@race", Convert.ToString(Dtrow("race")))
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@image_url", Convert.ToString(Dtrow("image_url")))
                    command.Connection = conn
                    command.CommandText = ("INSERT INTO [YESSSS] ([name],[type],[desc],[race],[image_url]) " &
                                                 "VALUES (@name,@type,@desc,@race,@image_url)")
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery()
                Else
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", Convert.ToString(DtRow("name")))
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@type", Convert.ToString(DtRow("type")))
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@desc", Convert.ToString(DtRow("desc")))
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@race", Convert.ToString(DtRow("race")))
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@image_url", Convert.ToString(DtRow("image_url")))
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@atk", Convert.ToInt32(DtRow("atk")))
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@def", Convert.ToInt32(DtRow("def")))
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@level", Convert.ToInt32(DtRow("level")))
                    command.Connection = conn
                    command.CommandText = ("INSERT INTO [YESSSS] ([name],[type],[desc],[race],[image_url],[atk],[def],[level]) " &
                                                  "VALUES (@name,@type,@desc,@race,@image_url,@atk,@def,@level)")
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery()

                End If
Next
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

Would you know how to cycle through all the XML elements and add their contents to an access table? Thankyou

Comment: Do `DataSet.ReadXmlSchema` and `.InferXmlSchema` mean anything to you?

Comment: I tried both nothing changed.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know vb.net that well. I would use VBA.

Comment: Try using the Xml Reader class.

Comment: it's only printing the value of the first element for each row